# Is there anyway I can ask python to explicitly treat all floats as 32bits even on a 64bit machine?

Tags: python

Is there anyway I can ask python to explicitly treat all floats as 32bits even on a 64bit machine?

I don't want to change the codes...

Comment: I believe you can install 32 bit Python on a 64 bit machine. I don't know if that affects the size of floats.

Comment: @ThomasK Machine word size is independent from floating point sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Python's `float` is built-in and set in stone. You can't change that. You could use [`float32`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) from numpy.

Comment: I know I can use numpy or array to do the trick, but there are just too many places too change (plus some machine-dependent issue). Just wonder whether there are some ways (or tools) to set up a pseudo-32bit environment one a 64bit machine which will "confuse" python to do a 32bit calculation.

Comment: First of all, whether the machine is 32 bit or 64 bit is neither here nor there when it comes to floating point. Single precision is 32 bit on 16 bit, 32 bit and 64 bit machines. Double precision, likewise, is 64 bit everywhere. And secondly, `float` is set in stone. You can't change what that means. Well, you could recompile Python and all the extensions, but that's really not practical.

Comment: @HailiangZhang, unless you have a very large array of floats why would you care if they're 32 or 64 bit? `numpy` seems like a good choice for those places where it matters.

Answer (score 1):

This size of the float is baked in at compilation time.  You can pass in a compile option to treat a C *double* as a *float* in a fresh python executable file.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

> Almost all machines today (July 2010) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision, so on input the computer strives to convert 0.1 to the closest fraction it can of the form J/2**N where J is an integer containing exactly 53 bits.

It looks like you will have the *same* sized floats on a 64 and 32 bit machine, neither of which will be 32 bits.

If you *must* have 32 bit floats, you can either use a virtual machine to run a version of python that *does* use 32 bit floats (though I've no idea if such a thing exists), or compile it yourself (no idea how).

You should be able to use the 64 bit python version on a 32 bit machine, though it shouldn't change the way floats work. I think the main difference between 32 bit and 64 bit python is RAM use - 64 bit can use more RAM, but it's also more RAM hungry.

Comment: You can't use 64 bit Python on a 32 bit machine.  You are correct that 32 vs. 64 is with regard to address space *not* the precision of floating point numbers.  64 bit also has to do with CPU register sizes, something that is well outside the scope of what Python will expose to you.